# Tableau Summing up aggregated data with FIXED

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation

Data granularity is per customer, per invoice date, per product type.

Generally the idea is simple:

We have a moving average calculation of the volume per week. MA based on last 12 weeks (MA Volume):
window_sum(sum([Volume]),-11,0)/window_count(count([Volume]), -11,0)

We need to see the deviation of the current week vs the MA for that week (Vol DIFF):
SUM([Volume])-[MA Calc]

We need to sum up the deviations for a fixed period of time (Year/Month)
Basically this should show us whether on average, for a given period of time, we deviate positively or negatively vs the base.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a66zZ.png)

Unfortunately I get errors like:

"Argument to SUM (an aggregate function) is already an aggregation, and cannot be further aggregated."
Or
"Level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the ATTR function"

Any ideas how I can go around this one?

Comment: your code is not that clear, anyway the Volume "inside" the SUM is the "MA Volume" of the first formula? if so have you already tried to get rid of the sum since it should be already aggregated?

Comment: No, Volume is data present in the original data. It is the volume against each invoice date occurrence. This is why MA volume sums it up.

Comment: so, could you please update your question with all the calculated field involved

Comment: Hi, there are only 2 calculated fields involved: 
- [MA Volume], which I now see is called [MA Calc], guess this is what caused the confusion
- [Vol DIFF]
the question is around how to sum up all values of Vol DIFF for a given Month or Year

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this one. Needed to add months to the view and then just WINDOW_SUM(Vol_DIFF).
Simple as that!